# GetTemplateChild / TemplatePart in Avalonia?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, avaloniaui

In WPF, you will declare XAML controls for code-behind use with TemplatePart, and then get a reference to those controls with GetTemplateChild.

How do you accomplish this in Avalonia UI?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set control Name inside template.

```
<Styles xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:controls="using:Sample.Controls">
  <Style Selector="controls|TestControl">
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <ControlTemplate>
        <TextBlock Name="PART_TextBlock" Text="Templated Control" />
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
</Styles>
```

In override OnApplyTemplate use e.NameScope.Find(...)

```
using Avalonia.Controls;
using Avalonia.Controls.Primitives;

namespace Sample.Controls
{
    public class TestControl : TemplatedControl
    {
        protected override void OnApplyTemplate(TemplateAppliedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate(e);

            var tb = e.NameScope.Find<TextBlock>("PART_TextBlock");
        }
    }
}
```